# Laravel: Query string to Eloquent filter

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I need a small function that will take a query string and turn it into one of 3 queries:

- WHERE column BETWEEN value AND value
- WHERE column = value
- WHERE column in (value, value, ...)

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
// USE: ?price[between][min]=0&price[between][max]=100&size[in][value]=L&size[in][value]=M

$filters = ['price', 'size'];

$products= Product::query();

foreach($filters as $filter)
{
    if(isset($input[$filter]) && array_filter($input[$filter][key($input[$filter])]))
    {
        sort($input[$filter][key($input[$filter])]);
        $products->{'where' . ucfirst(key($input[$filter]))}($filter, $input[$filter][key($input[$filter])]);
    }
}

return $products->get();
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is this a good approach?  If so, where's a good place for this logic?
2. Is there already a package to handle this logic?
3. If neither of the above, what's the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would simplify things. As for the place, I would put that in a ProductRepository (if you use the Repository Pattern). If you dont, I would place that in a function inside the model.
2. I have no idea. Haven't seen anything, but I was not looking for something like this.
3. Personally, the best way would be to create a function inside a repository, simplify the query string and the code.

You might have some problems with that query string, since a var_dump results in this:

```
array(2) {
    'price' =>
    array(1) {
        'between' =>
        array(2) {
            'min' => string(1) "0"
            'max' => string(3) "100"
        }
    }
    'size' =>
    array(1) {
        'in' =>
        array(1) {
            'value' => string(1) "M"
        }
    }
}
```

You see that the value `L` of variable `size` is missing because it was replaced with `M`. Sure, you can add another array, but if you can simplify to something like this:

```
?price[between]=0,100&size[in]=L,M
```

In any case, I would prefer this code, for readability purposes.

```
$qString = Input::all();

$model = App::make('Product');

$products = $model->where(function($query) use($qString) {
    foreach($qString as $column => $operations) {
        foreach($operations as $operator => $values) {
            switch($operator) {
                case 'between': 
                    $query->whereBetween($column, array($values['min'], $values['max']));
                    break;
                case 'in': 
                    $query->whereIn($column, $values);
                    break;
            }
            // or replace the switch with this:
            // $query->{'where' . ucfirst($operator)}($column, $values);
        }
    }
})->get();
```

Note that this has not been tested (although I use closures in my Repository methods and they work) and you might need to tweak this a bit.

Also be aware, if you choose a query string like I suggested, you might need some validations.